# when running npm start, to start a react project I get the following messages on the terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

When running `npm start`, to start a react project I get the following messages on the terminal:

> npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall open npm ERR! path /Users/eraldomaia/package.json npm ERR! errno -2 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/eraldomaia/package.json' npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file. npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! /Users/eraldomaia/.npm/_logs/2020-02-29T15_23_08_741Z-debug.log

I do not know what to do!

How can I solve this?

Comment: It seems like you trying to run the project from the different folder, in your case iti s Home folder.
You need to run it from the folder where you have bootstrapped or pulled your project.

Comment: this happened to me several times in `vscode` when I opened terminal with `ctrl+~`. You need `open the terminal/npm start`  from root folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run `npm start` at root folder of your project (where de package.json resides).

Comment: Thank you friend.
I just had to access the project folder via terminal first, then run npm.

Answer (score 0):

This is because npm is unable to find package.json in the directory where you are running `npm start`. Make sure your current working directory is the one where the project is actually cloned / bootstrapped.